# Particles that goes with 案内 in a ~てあげる sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, giving-and-receiving

I'm using Goukaku Dekiru N5·N4 book, and I'm confused about a question there. This is the question:

> 私が　りーさん（　　）あんないしてあげましょう

And the possible answers:

> 1. を　2. に　3. から　4. が

So, I answered number 2, に, but the answer book says is を. Why is this the case? I thought that Lee, in this case, would be the receiving part from the guidance that 私 does. With を it seems like 私 is guiding Lee like it'd guide Paris or New York.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

案内する takes particles as below.

- (person)を 案内する
- (person)に (place)を 案内する

So, both を and に are correct in the example question if it's asking for simply a correct answer. (Actually, I've seen this kind of incomplete questions for 日本語検定 books several times in this forum.)

Comment: I think this is not from an official exam, but is not encouraging to know there might be these kind of ambiguous questions. Thanks for your reply!